# Is any method called (or available to be called) after a system alert dialog is shown in iOS?

Tags: ios, alert

For a specific use case, it would be helpful to run a check right after the system pops up a dialog asking for permissions to access a privacy protected resource (music library, in this case). But that got me thinking:

Is there any way to respond to that dialog (or any system presented dialog) being dismissed?

I have tried to find any UIViewController methods getting called afterwards with no luck - hoping there might be something out there that I am unaware of.

Comment: You will get a resign active/become active notification And corresponding app delegate calls.

Comment: @Paulw11 well crud. I had my code in a NSNotification method for become active, but in the simulator the mediaplayer was throwing like 10-15seconds of errors and I was not patient enough to let it finish being bad, and it has been working the whole time. (the notification wouldnt fire till the errors were done, but the becomesActive in the appDelegate fired right away)